# How to install Cherokee web server on Debian Wheezy?

Tags: debian, package-management, software-installation, apt, webserver

I'm trying to install Cherokee webserver on Debian Wheezy. All the docs and websites that I've visited suggest that `apt-get install cherokee` will do it, but when I do that, I see:

```
$ apt-get install cherokee
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cherokee
```

When running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cherokee-webserver` ([as described in the docs](http://cherokee-project.com/doc/basics_installation_unix.html#APT)), I see:

```
-bash: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

[The docs](http://cherokee-project.com/downloads.html) says:

**Debian**

```
Install Cherokee from the apt repository
apt-get install cherokee cherokee-admin
Please, check the documentation for further
```

So I tried `apt-get install cherokee cherokee-admin`, which was also unable to locate the package. It doesn't make any sense: why would they tell you to use `apt`, if it's not available there? Some suggest that `cherokee` is dead, but I can see on the homepage it's very active, so something isn't right.

Should I build it from source?

On some forums they said that Cherokee never released a package for Wheezy. Is that true?

Comment: What does your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contain? Have you tried to update your apt cache via `apt-get update`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cherokee removed from Debian

I found this thread on the Cherokee mailing list which would seem to indicate that the package has been dropped from Debian all together.

- http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/cherokee/users/24168

> Cherokee was removed from Testing back in November, and has been 
>   removed from Unstable yesterday. But you can introduce it as a new 
>   package without changing the packaging. If you become a DM, I can 
>   sponsor you the first upload, and afterwards you can take care of it 
>   by yourself.

#### missing `add-apt-repository`

You're missing the application `add-apt-repository`. You can install it by installing this package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

#### Missing apps

On Debian and Ubuntu you can determine what package to install when you encounter a missing command line tool.

```
$ dpkg --search add-apt-repository
software-properties-common: /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
software-properties-common: /usr/share/man/man1/add-apt-repository.1.gz
```

You can also list the contents of a package by using `dpkg-query`:

```
$ dpkg-query -L software-properties-common | grep add-
/usr/share/man/man1/add-apt-repository.1.gz
/usr/bin/add-apt-repository
/usr/share/man/man1/apt-add-repository.1.gz
/usr/bin/apt-add-repository
```

#### apt-file

You can also install this tool, `apt-file` to search for files and find out what package they're included in:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

The first time you run it:

```
$ apt-file search add-apt-repository
E: The cache is empty. You need to run 'apt-file update' first.
```

So update it:

```
$ sudo apt-file update
```

Now with the cache inplace:

```
$ apt-file search add-apt-repository
software-properties-common: /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
software-properties-common: /usr/share/man/man1/add-apt-repository.1.gz
```

#### References

- [dpkg man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg.1.html)
- [dpkg-query man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/dpkg-query.1.html)
- [add-apt-repository not found [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018626/add-apt-repository-not-found)

Comment: thanks sir, i'm accepting your answer since i am indeed missing oftware-properties-common. As for cherokee, if it's not active, i'm going for nginx, i wanted to try hosting django on it, but it's not worth it

Comment: @Fischer - nginx. Yes I use this on several sites that I support and it's an excellent webserver. Great community and docs.

Answer (score 2):

Cherokee was removed from Debian [in April 2012](http://packages.qa.debian.org/c/cherokee/news/20120428T111526Z.html) since maintainer abandoned the package. Unfortunately, the documentation hasn't been updated since then, and the PPA don't include debian-specific builds.

> Should I build it from source?

That would be the best course of action. Use the [guide that provides Cherokee](http://cherokee-project.com/doc/basics_installation_unix.html) that will build Cherokee for your system natively. You can, also, instead using `make install` use `check-install` that will [create a .deb file that you can uninstall later](http://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall).

> On some forums they said that Cherokee never released a package for Wheezy, is that true?

Yes, the package was never released for Wheezy, only for Squeeze (oldstable). You can check the current status of the package [here](http://packages.qa.debian.org/c/cherokee.html).

Comment: thanks a lot, i'm not gonna go for it, if there's no support for it, i don't really need it, i heard that it was better than njinx, wanted to give it a try, if no future support, i don't really have to install

Comment: @Fischer - nginx.